# Importing Az Powershell module in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell

I'm trying to use PowerShell from C#. I want to import the Az.Compute module to use cmdlets, but it's not working.

```
        InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();

        iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Bypass;
        Console.WriteLine(iss.ExecutionPolicy);
        //iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "Az.Compute" });
        iss.ImportPSModulesFromPath(@"C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Compute");

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
        runspace.Open();

        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.Runspace = runspace;

        Collection<PSObject> servers = ps
            .AddCommand("Get-AzVM")
            .Invoke();
```

First I needed to bypass the execution policy to be able to import module. I'm using ImportPSModule method from the InitialSessionSate class. When I'm running this code I get an exception at Get-AzVM: `System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: 'The 'Get-AzVM' command was found in the module 'Az.Compute', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Compute'.'`

If I run Get-InstalledModule in the developer powershell the module is there. I'v tried by importing the module from path, but still get the exception when trying to use cmdlets from the module.

Answer (score 0):

The above error is due to the `Az.Compute` module was not loaded properly.
You can try the below workarounds to let the `Get-AzVM` cmdlet work and also the module to get loaded correctly:

- `Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser` after  running this cmdlet, restart the Powershell and then run again this `import-module az.compute` cmd.
- Also you can check the logs of PowerShellCore/Operational from Event viewer, if any errors are found then update the packages to the [latest versions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/#readme-body-tab).